# What pro forma documents do people use to talk to clients about web development

Tags: planning, estimation, resource-planning

This is a very general question and I believe it will be relevant to other people in my situation.

I've been involved as a hobbyist in web design and development for over 2 years now. I have produced a number of websites but charged nothing or a token gesture to the people (my friends) that I've worked with.

Going forward as a freelance web developer, I'd like to know what tools do people use to engage their clients with

In all my successful ventures and going forward, I have used [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), it offers the versatility of being designed from mobile devices upwards (I explain that to the client).

One issue with bootstrap, is, it doesn't provide a pretty backend WYSIWYG editor (like wordpress does) for the client to use - This means that I cannot charge a one-off payment to the client but instead have to negotiate a long term arrangement. The long term arrangement isn't the issue, but getting there is. In many cases clients want a solution they can manage themselves, and I refuse to use wordpress (snob - maybe).

So, these are my questions:

1. **Negotiation:** Whats the best way to negotiate a long term arrangement in terms of webpage design, hosting and ongoing maintenance? I gather charging an hourly rate for work done when the site is complete is the obvious answer but how do people factor this in to their original project proposal?

   2. **Template Documents:** Are there any pro forma documents used for web design and costing that people have found to be beneficial?
   3. **Time scales:** When it comes to proposing time scales for the implementation and having read: [How granular should an estimate be for building a web page?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/8070/how-granular-should-an-estimate-be-for-building-a-web-page) are their any pro forma documents that people use to do that?

Comment: Many thanks for making this more readable Tiago.

Comment: On a side note, Bootstrap is a css library, as such it can be integrated with various platforms including wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Question 1: we use the free or cheap edition of Balsamiq (also
   available online in the browser). Everything understands how to use
   it and it allows XML (BMML) format to exchange ideas.
2. Question 2: I
   don't understand the question. Do you mean templates?
3. Question 3: If
   you mean templates, I assume the answer is "Yes". But I think the
   question is something different. Please reprehrase.

Comment: 1. When you say the cheap edition, do you mean the $79 one?
(thank you)
2. I mean http://bootstraphero.com/ with more functionality.

3. Is a question about documentation from B2C -> how does one invoice for web design.

Comment: Ah, ok. 1: cheap is approx USD 79, free is online. 2: We use DotNetNuke as Content Management System. Still many users find it too hard to use, but when they are willing to spend time they can do (we have non-techies using it all the time, but it requires training). 3: Do you invoice locally or internationally? From what country?

Comment: Thanks Guido for the reply, excuse the length of time taken to reply, sleep was in order... Invoiced from the UK locally.

Will look at netnuke :)

Comment: Clear. The original questions have been edited, so I am a little lost, but from my knowledge on UK you can invoice by the hour or fixed price. And deliver with or without intellectual ownership. Pro forma documents: maybe these instructions of a collegeau help you http://www.invantive.com/about-invantive/news/entryid/1025/gratis-online-cursus-microsoft-excel-2010-deel-1. You also might want to consider a free or paid service application for subledger accounts receivables.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with business.

Answer (score 0):

> One issue with bootstrap, is, it doesn't provide a pretty backend WYSIWYG editor (like wordpress does) for the client to use

Here are a few WYSIWYG editors for Bootstrap:

- [Pingendo](https://pingendo.com)
- [Bootstrap Studio](https://bootstrapstudio.io)
- [Layoutit! Bootstrap Builder](https://www.layoutit.com)
- [CkEditor: Bootstrap Editor](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/bootstrap-editor)
- [Visual JavaScript editor for the Bootstrap grid system](https://github.com/Frontwise/grid-editor)
- [Bootply](https://www.bootply.com)
- [JS+ Bootstrap Editor](https://js.plus/products/bootstrap-editor)

**References**

- [18 Essential Bootstrap UI Editors](https://mashable.com/2013/10/20/bootstrap-editors/)
- [Best Practices for Negotiating Cloud-Based Software Contracts](http://www.doncio.navy.mil/CHIPS/ArticleDetails.aspx?ID=4690)
- [KPMG Leeyo Subscribed 2015 - Adoption of the New Revenue Standard](https://www.slideshare.net/TimLashua/kpmg-leeyo)
- [Deferred Revenue](http://proformative.com/questions/deferred-revenue)